# Why does pyautogui.center return an error in this situation?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to make a program that reads a mathematical equation and solves it using the Windows calculator. I did it in school, it was working, however, now that I try it at home it doesn't.
There is the part of the code:

```
import time, pyautogui
button_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('1.png')
button1point = pyautogui.center(button_location)
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Calculator\main.py", line 39,
in module button1point = pyautogui.center(button_location)**

Answer (score 0):

**When your image is not on screen then it will return none.** Try this code and **bring the image on your screen**.

```
import time, pyautogui

while True:
    try:

        button_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('1.png')
        button1point = pyautogui.center(button_location)
        print(button1point)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```