# Python returns 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable' even though I haven't used sort, reverse, append, etc

Tags: python

Sorry if the problem I have has already been solved by someone else, but most of other people's code have problems because they used sort, reverse, append, etc however I didn't, so I don't know why I'm getting TypeError: 'NoneType'.

I'm trying to make code to automate gold mining in a game.

The full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yao\Documents\goldafkfarm\goldafkfarm.py", line 14, in <module>
    allbutton_centre = pyautogui.center(allbutton)
  File "C:\Users\yao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 649, in center
    return Point(coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

My code:

```
#python 3.7.0

import keyboard
import pyautogui
import win32api
import win32con
from pyautogui import *

# X: 1815 Y: 1021 RGB: (255, 185,  44) EMPTY HUNGER BAR
# X: 1617 Y: 1020 RGB                  FULL HUNGER BAR
# X: 1493 Y:   93 RGB: (255, 255, 255) ALL
# X:  960 Y:   47 RGB: (119, 179,   0) PLAY BUTTON
# X:  962 Y:  536 RGB: (246, 230, 173) GOLD
sunfruit = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('sunfruit.png')
allbutton = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('allbutton.png')
allbutton_centre = pyautogui.center(allbutton)


def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.01)    
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)


if keyboard.is_pressed('m') is True:
    while keyboard.is_pressed('q') is False:

        if pyautogui.pixel(1815, 1021) != (255, 185, 44):  # If empty
            if pyautogui.pixel(1493, 93) != (255, 255, 255):  # Check if no all option is not found
                pyautogui.press('c')  # Press c for inventory
                click(allbutton_centre)
            while pyautogui.pixel(1617, 1020) != (255, 185, 44):  # If not full
                try:
                    sunfruit_centre = (pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('sunfruit.png'))  # Try to locate sunfruit
                except TypeError:
                    print('Could not locate sunfruit')
                    while True:
                        click(960, 47)  # Click start button if there's sunfruit
                else:
                    click(sunfruit_centre)  # Eat sunfruit
        click(962, 536)
```

Comment: Perhaps `pyautogui.locateOnScreen('allbutton.png')` returns `None`.

Comment: You are getting this error because: coords is None So, for each one of these you will get: coords[0],coords[1],coords[2],coords[3] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: See the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71206369/why-does-pyautogui-center-return-an-error-in-this-situation)

Comment: You can assert that *coords == None* so you'll need to do some debugging to determine why that might be